# Vis.js won't zoom-in further than scale 1.0 with .fit()

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I am using the library Vis.js to display a Network.
For my application, I need the network to be displayed fullscreen, with the nodes almost touching the borders of its container.

The problem comes from network.fit(); it won't Zoom-In further than scale '1.0'

I wrote a Fiddle to showcase the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/v1467x1d/12/

```
var nodeSet = [
    {id:1,label:'big'},
    {id:2,label:'big too'} ];

var edgeSet = [ 
    {from:1, to:2} ];

var nodes = new vis.DataSet(nodeSet);
var edges = new vis.DataSet(edgeSet);

var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
};
var options = {};

var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
network.fit();
console.log( 'scale: '+ network.getScale() ); // Always 1
```

How can I force Vis to zoom until the network is fullscreen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Richard said - now, this method does not work as expected. You can use a custom method, as a concept:

```
function bestFit() {

  network.moveTo({scale:1}); 
  network.stopSimulation();
   
  var bigBB = { top: Infinity, left: Infinity, right: -Infinity, bottom: -Infinity }
  nodes.getIds().forEach( function(i) {
    var bb = network.getBoundingBox(i);
    if (bb.top < bigBB.top) bigBB.top = bb.top;
    if (bb.left < bigBB.left) bigBB.left = bb.left;
    if (bb.right > bigBB.right) bigBB.right = bb.right;
    if (bb.bottom > bigBB.bottom) bigBB.bottom = bb.bottom;  
  })
  
  var canvasWidth = network.canvas.body.container.clientWidth;
  var canvasHeight = network.canvas.body.container.clientHeight; 

  var scaleX = canvasWidth/(bigBB.right - bigBB.left);
  var scaleY = canvasHeight/(bigBB.bottom - bigBB.top);
  var scale = scaleX;
  if (scale * (bigBB.bottom - bigBB.top) > canvasHeight ) scale = scaleY;

  if (scale>1) scale = 0.9*scale;
 
  network.moveTo({
    scale: scale,
    position: {
        x: (bigBB.right + bigBB.left)/2,
      y: (bigBB.bottom + bigBB.top)/2
    }
  })
  
}
```

[ http://jsfiddle.net/dv4qyeoL/ ]

Comment: Saved my life... then brought me to despair when some networks got cut on top and bottom with no apprent cause. Untill I found the bug, which re-saved my life for the second time in one day :-)  Do you agree with following edit: `if (scale * (bigBB.bottom - bigBB.top) > canvasHeight ) scale = scaleY;` ?

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry it is impossible to do this using `network.fit`. Here is the relevant [code](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/0666cb142c1fedaf63580a3cd94cb99f210d4325/lib/network/modules/View.js#L85).

However, you can patch it yourself and include the modified version into your application which should then work as expected.
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0y8hzjfh/) (line 38337 for the modification). I can't promise it won't break something else though.

Relevant code :

```
/*if (zoomLevel > 1.0) {
  zoomLevel = 1.0;
} else if (zoomLevel === 0) {
  zoomLevel = 1.0;
}*/
if (zoomLevel === 0) {
  zoomLevel = 1.0;
}
```